# jQuery Validation Plug-In - Requiring File Inputs?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am having difficulty getting the [jQuery validation plug](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a file field. It works for all surrounding elements, but not the file. For example, a snippet of my HTML

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-sm"><label class="col-md-6">I select direct deposit for disbursement of my pay. <input class="required paySelectionRadio" type="radio" id="directDeposit" value="DD" name="PaySelection" /></label><label class="col-md-2 control-label">Initials</label><div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control input-sm" type='text' name='DirectDepositInitials' id="directDepositInitials" /></div></div>

            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Account Number</label><div class="col-md-4"><input type='text' class="form-control input-sm" id="accountNumber" name='PaySelectionAccountNumber' /></div>
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Routing Number</label><div class="col-md-4"><input type='text' class="form-control input-sm" id="routingNumber" name='PaySelectionRoutingNumber' /></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">ATTACH A VOIDED CHECK</label><div class="col-md-4"><input type="file" id="voidedCheck" name="PaySelectionCheck" /></div>
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Account Type: </label><div class="col-md-4"><select class='form-control input-sm' id="accountType" name='PaySelectionAccountType'><option value="">Select..</option><option value="Checking">Checking</option><option value="Savings">Savings</option></select></div>
            </div>
```

The fields above, aside from "paySelectionRadio" are conditionally required.

```
$("#directDepositInitials").rules("add", {
        required: {
            depends: function (el) { return $("#directDeposit").is(":checked"); }
        }
});

$("#accountType").rules("add", {
    required: {
        depends: function (el) { return $("#directDeposit").is(":checked"); }
    },

});

$("#voidedCheck").rules("add", {
    required: {
        depends: function (el) { return $("#directDeposit").is(":checked"); }
    }
});

$("#routingNumber").rules("add",{
    required: {
        depends: function (el) { return $("#directDeposit").is(":checked"); }
    }

});

$("#accountNumber").rules("add", {
    required: {
        depends: function (el) { return $("#directDeposit").is(":checked"); }
    }

});
```

This works properly for all the other fields, but not "voidedCheck". It is as if the plug-in is not even finding it. For example, this is the script generated when I attempt to submit the form without proper input.

```
to act on those instructions or until Company or Financial Instituion cancels the direct deposit arrangement.</p>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm"><label class="col-md-6">I select direct deposit for disbursement of my pay. <input class="required paySelectionRadio valid" id="directDeposit" value="DD" name="PaySelection" type="radio"></label><label class="col-md-2 control-label">Initials</label><div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control input-sm error" name="DirectDepositInitials" id="directDepositInitials" type="text"><label for="directDepositInitials" class="error">This field is required.</label></div></div>

            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Account Number</label><div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control input-sm error" id="accountNumber" name="PaySelectionAccountNumber" type="text"><label for="accountNumber" class="error">This field is required.</label></div>
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Routing Number</label><div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control input-sm error" id="routingNumber" name="PaySelectionRoutingNumber" type="text"><label for="routingNumber" class="error">This field is required.</label></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">ATTACH A VOIDED CHECK</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="voidedCheck" name="PaySelectionCheck" type="file"></div>
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Account Type: </label><div class="col-md-4"><select class="form-control input-sm error" id="accountType" name="PaySelectionAccountType"><option value="">Select..</option><option value="Checking">Checking</option><option value="Savings">Savings</option></select><label for="accountType" class="error">This field is required.</label></div>
            </div>
```

As you can see, the other fields have the "error" class appropriately assigned. The file field has neither an error or valid class associated with it.

What might the issue be?

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors showing up in the console?

Comment: Just Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead (in the jQuery file) and a warning about passwords and not using https.